# Method to keep memory area as constant in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

In C++ I am writing to a memory area with the help of a char pointer. My char pointer is the following:

```
  unsigned char * writer;
  *(writer++)=0xF1; //example of write
```

Now my problem is that once I write...some other write within my program is able to write over this data..due to which I am getting incorrect results when I read. Since I am writing only once..is there some way in C/C++ such that I am able to keep this memory area as constant (untouched)..so that no other part of the program writes over it.

Comment: I honestly don't get it..

Comment: You need to eliminate wild pointers and out-of-bounds array access.  Tools such as `Electric Fence` can help you find pointer bugs.

Comment: I assume you actually make the pointer point to something valid, instead of leaving it uninitialized?

Comment: It is up to you as a developer to ensure your code does not write over memory you don't want to change.

Comment: Do you mean as a debugging tool?  If such a thing existed, your program would only be contradicting itself, right?  You want your program to make this memory constant **and** it wants to write to that memory.  Who wins?  What happens?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please clarify if this is a question about a multi-threaded program or not.

Comment: If your program is bugged (which seems to be the case) then C++ offers no guarantees over how it will behave. So I would find and fix the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain with enough detail to give an exact answer, but I would have thought simply passing the pointer around as `const` would be enough to do what you want:

```
const unsigned char *writer;
```

Perhaps wrap the write functionality into a class and only allow `const` access to the memory:

```
class MemWriter
{
private:
    unsigned char *writer;
public:
    const unsigned char *getMemory() const
    {
        return writer;
    }
    //
    // Other methods to perform the writing defined here
    //
};
```

This won't actually stop code from casting the pointer to non-`const` and writing into it, but it will at least show your intention that the memory is readonly.

Answer (score 4):

Not portably, no.

You might be able to use the facilities provided by your OS to mark the entire memory page as read-only. This may or may not work for you depending on whether you can isolate the byte in question into a  dedicated memory page. It also is a bit of a sledgehammer approach.

If you want to do this in order to work around a bug, then a better approach is to find and fix the bug. For example, if you suspect that there's a memory corruption, [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) is an extremely useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to protect against routines that you can trust not to cast a pointer-to-const to a pointer-to-non-const but that might inadvertently write to a buffer that they should treat as constant (e.g., because of a typographical error or because of thoughtlessness when writing the routine), then simply convert the pointer to a pointer to const and only pass that to other routines. The compiler will generally issue warnings or errors when a routine attempts to write via a pointer-to-const. (There are some holes in this, such as the `strchr` routine.) When you later free the memory, you may need either to have a record of the original pointer to non-const, or you will have to “forcibly” cast the pointer-to-const back to pointer-to-non-const.

If you are trying to protect against bugs in which a routine may overflow a buffer or otherwise go significantly astray, then check whether your computing platform offers the `mprotect` call. This will require allocating memory in page-size units at page-aligned addresses (for which your platform might have a call such as `valloc`). Again, when it is time to release the memory, you may need to change the protection to permit writing again.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ nothing prevents you from writing to an address space available to a program, provided you have its address - the 32bit/64bit integer number. Use keywords like const to prevent accidental overwrites, and make your intentions clear to the reader. In the code below let us see how we can play around address number, assuming a 32-bit machine.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 998979789;

    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    int j = (int)(&i);// get the address number

    char * m = (char*)j; // change to a char*

    char old = m[0]; // store the  char for later use

    m [0] = 'A'; // write over the memory

    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    m[0] = old; // again write to bring it back

    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```